# cvQueryFrame does not return cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

I have old project, where I did something like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

(...)

CvCapture* capture;
cv::Mat frame;

capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

(...)
```

And it worked.

Now I have created new project and now I have error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'IplImage *' to 'cv::Mat *'

Only difference between these projects I notice is that the new one is written in CLR C++. Both use openCV 2.4.11.

Why cvQueryFrame() in my old project was able to return cv::Mat and new one doesnt? What did I missed?

Comment: please try to **avoid** CvCapture, IplImage, cvQueryFrame, et al. refactor your code instead, and use cv::VideoCapture and cv::Mat

Comment: @berak Seems OP is aware of not using old C opencv API. Question itself is clearly worth asking since he is using this API in his old project  and he's asking about backward compability (you cannot assume that he's able to refactor his code, that was not the question he asked)